# Spotify api search, not getting results for autocomplete search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm very new here and fairly new to programming but from an example code from an old echonest code example I had working, I have been trying to now use the Spotify API to achieve the same thing.

I have modified it all to what I believe should make it work but it isn't :(

Is anyone able to help see what I might be doing wrong here?

Code is below:

There is a simple form for now for testing of:

```
<input id="#q" />
```

Then some javascript:

```
(document).ready(function() {

    $("#q").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    type: "artist",
                    limit: 3,
                    format: "json",
                    q: q
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.artists, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
            window.location.href = "#" + ui.item.value;
        },
    });
});
```

The raw json results for a search for "Cher" for example would be:
[json results](https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=cher)

I have searched as much as I can on here and can't see anyone else with the same issue.

Thank you

Comment: what's not working? are you getting a bad response? are you getting a javascript error? is your computer turned on?

Comment: remove `#` from `id="#q"`. Next add `$` before `(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

try to change followings:
`<input id="#q" />` to `<input id="q" />`

`q: q` to `q: request.term` (see https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

And, as Dave said: add `$` before `(document).ready`